# Need help with determining if sequences $a_{n}=\frac{n+3}{n+2}$ and $a_{n}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ are increasing or decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I'm struggling with a problem that asks me to determine whether the following sequences are increasing or decreasing:

a) $a_{n}=\frac{n+3}{n+2}$

b) $a_{n}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$

For part (a), I tried to find $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ and simplify it to see if it was positive or negative. After some algebra, I got:

$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\frac{1}{n+2}$

Since $n+2$ is always positive, $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ is always positive. Therefore, the sequence is increasing.

For part (b), I followed the same process and got:

$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=-\frac{2}{(n+1)(n+3)}$

Since $(n+1)(n+3)$ is always positive, $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ is always negative. Therefore, the sequence is decreasing.

Could someone please verify if my answers are correct or not? If I made a mistake, I would appreciate any guidance on how to approach the problem correctly.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your result for $a_{n+1}-a_n$ for part (a) is incorrect

Comment: Writing out a few terms of each sequence could help get a feel for the problem.

Comment: Hint, for the first part: $\frac{n+3}{n+2}=1+\frac{1}{n+2}$. Works similarly for the second.

Comment: is there a reason you included tags like taylor expansion and power series? Because they don't seem relevant.

Comment: @Hersh: I bet this is from a section about sequences in a chapter about series, power series in a calculus or analysis book. Wrong tag but it may hard for a student to know it.

Comment: Alternatively, consider $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ instead of $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$.

Answer (score 4):

Your computations are incorrect. In the first case, $a_{n+1}-a_n=-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}<0$ so $a_n$ is decreasing. In the second case, $a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{2}{(n+2)(n+1)}>0$ so the sequence is increasing. Your general reasoning is good though.

Alternatively, since $a_n>0$ for every $n$, you can also compute $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. Then:

1. $a_n$ is increasing if and only if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$ for every $n$
2. $a_n$ is decreasing if and only if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$ for every $n$

For some sequences, this would lead to easier computations.

Finally, in a), you can also write $a_n=1+\frac{1}{n+2}$ and since $\frac{1}{n+2}$ is decreasing, $a_n$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

For first part $$a_n=\frac{n+3}{n+2}=1+\frac{1}{n+2}$$
$n$ increases $\implies$ $a_n$ decreases

For second part $$a_n=\frac{n-1}{n+1}=1-\frac{2}{n+1}$$
$n$ increases $\implies$ $a_n$ increases

---

This is because in first case when $n$ increases the fraction $\frac{1}{n+2}$ decreases. This means everytime we increase $n$ we add something smaller than the previous value as $\frac{1}{n+2}>\frac{1}{(n+1)+2}$

In second case we're subtracting so the opposite of first case will happen.